# Prism 4: RequestNavigate() not working

Tags: c#, prism, prism-4

I am building a demo app to learn the navigation features of Prism 4. The app has two modules--each one has three Views:

- A UserControl with a text block ("Welcome to Module A")
- A RibbonTab (using a Region Adapter), and
- An Outlook-style Task Button (like Outlook's Mail, Calendar, and so on)

The Shell has three named regions: "RibbonRegion", "TaskButtonRegion", and "WorkspaceRegion". The Views load into these regions. To test the basic setup, I registered all three Views with the Prism Region Manager, so that they would load at startup, and all worked as expected.

Next, I modified the setup so that only the Task Buttons would load on startup. Other Views would load only on request, by clicking a Task Button. My module initializers look like this:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    /* We register the Task Button with the Prism Task Button Region because we want it
     * to be displayed immediately when the module is loaded, and for the lifetime of
     * the application. */

    // Register Task Button with Prism Region
    m_RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TaskButtonRegion", typeof(ModuleATaskButton));

    /* We register these objects with the Unity container because we don't want them
     * instantiated until we navigate to this module. */ 

    // Register View and Ribbon Tab as singletons with Unity container
    m_Container.RegisterType(typeof(ModuleAView), "ModuleAView", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    m_Container.RegisterType(typeof(ModuleARibbonTab), "ModuleARibbonTab", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

When the user clicks a Task Button, it invokes an ICommand object that calls `IRegionManager.RequestNavigate()` to show the views:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    // Initialize
    var regionManager = m_ViewModel.RegionManager;

    // Show Ribbon Tab
    var moduleARibbonTab = new Uri("ModuleARibbonTab", UriKind.Relative);
    regionManager.RequestNavigate("RibbonRegion", moduleARibbonTab);

    // Show View
    var moduleAView = new Uri("ModuleAView", UriKind.Relative);
    regionManager.RequestNavigate("WorkspaceRegion", moduleAView);
}
```

The command is being invoked when a Task Button is clicked, but what I get is this:

[image: Demo app screen shot]

The UserControl is apparently loading as a `System.Object`, and I suspect the RibbonTab is loading the same. I think the problem is with my `RequestNavigate()` call, or my registration with Unity. But I can't identify the problem.

Can anyone shed any light on what's going on? Thanks for your help.

Comment: would you mind checking this out ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309661/navigation-not-occurring

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally figured this one out. The answer is in the *Developer's Guide to Microsoft Prism* (Ver 4), pp. 120-121. It has two parts:

First, the `UserControl` and `RibbonTab` objects were resolving from Unity as `System.Object` types. That's a limitation of Unity and the overload that I used to register the view objects. To get them to resolve to the correct types, you need to use a different overload for `IUnityContainer.RegisterType()`:

```
// Register other view objects with DI Container (Unity)
m_Container.RegisterType<Object, ModuleAView>("ModuleAView");
m_Container.RegisterType<Object, ModuleARibbonTab>("ModuleARibbonTab");
```

This overload maps Unity's native `System.Object` resolution to the correct type for the view requested. See the note on p. 120 of the *Developer's Guide*.

The second problem wasn't explicitly stated in my question, but it occured when I fixed the first problem. I wanted each module's `RibbonTab` to be removed when I switched to the other module. Since my Ribbon Region acts like an `ItemsControl`, both `RibbonTabs` ended up being shown--Module A's `RibbonTab` wasn't unloaded when I switched to Module B. To solve that problem, I implemented `IRegionMemberLifetime` on the `RibbonTab` classes. That issue is covered on p. 121 of the *Developer's Guide*.

BTW, I implemented the `IRegionMemberLifetime` interface on the View objects, rather than their View Models, because the interface does not impact the back end of the app, only the view object.

Comment: +1 You just made my day. Exactly my problem. Plus solution :-)

Comment: Thanks for answering your question so we can all see the results.

Comment: yes it worked for me. But question is if I need to register type interface for the view it for g: registerType<IViewA,ViewA>("ViewA"); it has the same problem what you faced how can we fix it